# How to create tube like hair?

Tags: particles, physics, hair

Is there any way to create hair the way Ducky is in this video without converting it to a mesh?

[image: Tube like hair]

Or is there any way to add geometry to a hair particle system?

I want to keep it as a particle system so that it can wave and swing around, but I want a low number of thick hair strands.

I've tried converting the particle system and converting curve from mesh, but this makes it static and doesn't allow the hair to move.

I've also tried changing hair in render properties to strip and playing with  the hair shape in the particle settings and it just makes wider flat hair particles, but I want 3 dimensional.
[image: Flat 2D Hair]

Tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4nWer8eP6Y&t=205s

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cycles

Use *Particles system > Render as Path*
and under *Hair Shape* set thickness and disable **Close Tip**

[image]

Comment: Dammit Vklidu. You're a genius!

Comment: Yes, I am ... Genious in oblivion ... I wanted to answer you six days ago ... Great if still helpful :)